# Como fazer para um ou mais campo dentro da tela execute função javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Tenho uma função javascript que deve ser executada quando qualquer um dos dois campos sejam realizados qualquer tipo de alteração.

A princípio somente o campo **#DataAbate** quando é realizado um change executa o script mas quero que o **#QuantidadeAnimais** também execute a função.

A pergunta é como fazer para que **#DataAbate** e **#QuantidadeAnimais** sem redundância de código.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#DataAbate").change(function () {
   $("#SequenciaInicial").empty();
   $("#SequenciaFinal").empty();
   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetSequencia")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { dataAbate: $("#DataAbate").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, data) {

                    document.getElementById('NumeroLote').value = parseInt(data.NumeroLote) + 1;
                    document.getElementById('SequenciaInicial').value = parseInt(data.SequenciaFinal) + 1;
                    document.getElementById('SequenciaFinal').value = parseInt(data.SequenciaFinal) + parseInt($("#QuantidadeAnimais").val());
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Falha ao buscar Proprietario.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
 )}
```

Comment: Pode fazer $('#campo, #campo2') ou com classnames , $('.campo'), o classname pode ser identificado em mais de um elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 -**

Pra dispararcom os dois id's diferentes :

```
$("#DataAbate, #QuantidadeAnimais").change(function () {
//seu codigo
})
```

Ou com classnames:

```
$(".classnameEmComumEntreOsCampos").change(function () {
//seu codigo
})
```

**2 -**

Para adicionar um classname direto ao HTML:

```
<elemento class="classname"></elemento>
```

Ou para adicionar o classname via jQuery:

```
$("#DataAbate, #QuantidadeAnimais").addClass('NomeDoClassname');
```

Comment: Amigo AntraxisBR e se caso seja obrigatório pelo menos o campo #DataAbate estar preenchido, pois funcionou mas somente se o campo #DataAbate preenchido.

Comment: @Cyberlacs qual dos dois ? com classname ou id ? é pra funcionar com os dois, vou fazer um exemplo com a função completa funcionando

Comment: Com este modelo que funcionou perfeitamente o Campo #DataAbate tem que estar preenchido --------> $("#DataAbate, #QuantidadeAnimais").change(function () {
//seu codigo
})

Comment: @Cyberlacs mas ja resolveu sou problema ? ou preciso melhorar a resposta?

Comment: Resolveu o problema sim, mas falta a prioridade do campo #DataAbate estar preenchido, somente este

Comment: Qualquer coisa faço outra pergunta

Comment: Me diga uma coisa antes de eu arrumar aqui, ele não funciona se o campo #DataAbate não estiver preenchido mesmo quando você mudar o outro campo ? e o campo #DataAbate é qual campo ? select ou input ou outro